# In the Xcode lldb debugger, what does <parent is NULL> mean?

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

I'm always getting **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**, so I look to see which variable is pointing to `NULL` and all I see is that one of my variables (sometimes several) has

> < parent is NULL >

next to it. The problem is I don't really know what this means and I can't seem to find anything from a google search or anything about it. I'm thinking this means that that is the `NULL` variable I'm trying to access, but then the message  doesn't make much sense. Anybody know a little more on this?

Comment: Is this variable Objective-C class or C++ class or struct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It simply means the variable is a pointer to an object and the pointer is `NULL`.

From the [LLDB source](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/source/Core/ValueObjectChild.cpp):

```
if (addr == LLDB_INVALID_ADDRESS)
{
    m_error.SetErrorString ("parent address is invalid.");
}
else if (addr == 0)
{
    m_error.SetErrorString ("parent is NULL");
}
else
...
```

Comment: That is a perfect explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I too had "parent is NULL" when i printed description of my array object

Thanks to trojanfoe's answer, I was able to see that I was returning my array incorrectly. I simply changed:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)allItems {
   return self.allItems;
}
```

to:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)allItems {
   return _allItems;
}
```

Hope this helps!